# How to put div inside bigger div with some decoation?

Tags: css

I am new in web design, I would like to create a template like in the image below with CSS?
and how to make the height of big div dynamically change according to its content

[image]

My HTML code is

```
  <section class="results">
    <h2>The result</h2>
    <div id="results"></div>
  </section>
```

My CSS code is

```
.results h2 {
   background-color: rgb(138, 17, 68);
   width: fit-content;
   border-radius: 5px;
   padding: 5px 15px;
   color: blanchedalmond;
   font-size: 30px;
}
.results {
   background-color:rgba(255, 228, 225,0.5);
   border: rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
   max-width: 75vw;
   height: fit-content;
   border-radius: 10px;
   box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
   margin-left: 50%;
   margin-right: -50%;
   transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried: markup and CSS. This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: sorry, I'm new in web design, I added the code
can you reopen the topic again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one of the issues you ran into when centering the h2 was setting `width: fit-content;`. Fit content uses all the available space that it can and not less than the content available. And given that it's a heading tag, its display property is `display: block;` by default so it uses *all* the space of whatever container it is in. Switching it to `width: max-content;` makes it so that it only uses as much space as it needs but not less, so it doesn't wrap to another line.

For the big div, if you don't specify the height manually, it will default to `height: auto;` and will be fully responsive automatically. You can set a `min-height' property if you want to it doesn't go below certain height, but there's no need to do anything else.

Also, looking at your code, that's not quite how border property works. It goes `border: [width of a border(pixels|em|rem)][style of border(solid|dashed|dotted)][color of border(hex|rgba)]` right now you only have the color specified.

Here's the modified code. It's not perfect and I honestly would probably use `display: flex;` to center the elements in the middle, but it seems to match your design close enough.

HTML

```
<section class="results">
  <h2>Results</h2>
  <div id="results">
    Placeholder text, add whatever you want.
  </div>
</section>
```

CSS

```
.results {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 80%;
  max-width: 500px;
}

.results h2 {
  background-color: white;
  width: max-content;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
  border: 1px solid black;
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

#results {
  padding: 35px 15px 15px 15px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0,.5);
}
```